# Django Image Upload, Image Is Never Stored

Tags: python, django

I'm having some trouble with a django blog that I'm working on, and I was wondering if someone could help me out.

https://github.com/kevin-reaves/Blog

localhost:8000/posts/create

Basically, when I go to create a blog post using the creation form everything seems to work aside from uploading the actual image. The admin console seems to think there's an image at the correct location, but nothing gets uploaded there.

Here's the password for the admin console

admin

password123

Edit: Added some relevant code

```
<form action="{% url 'create' %}" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}


<p>Title:</p>
<input type="text" name="title"/>
<br/>
<p>Image:</p>
<input type="file" name="image"/>


def create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST['title'] and request.POST['body']:
            post = Post()
            post.title = request.POST['title']
            post.pub_date = timezone.datetime.now()
            post.image = request.POST['image']
            post.body = request.POST['body']
            post.author = request.user
            post.save()
            return redirect('home')

class Post(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, db_column="user", default=1)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='media', blank=True)
    body = HTMLField()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick find... you need two changes this to work.

1. Add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your html form
2. use `request.FILES['image']`

Comment: I'll try those, the enctype caused a MultiValueDictKeyError by itself

Comment: I thought I'd submitted a comment saying this worked a few days ago.

The fix worked, thanks for the help =)

Comment: Glad you found the answer